# Whats the correct way to modify the author pane to add profile fields?

Tags: 7

I want to add several fields from the user profile to the author pane.

Within the author-pane.tpl.php file, I added the following lines.

```
$fname = $account->field_profile_firstname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']; 
    $lname = $account->field_profile_lastname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']; 
    $dob = $account->field_profile_dob[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $bio = $account->field_profile_bio[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $phone = $account->field_profile_phone[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $marital = $account->field_profile_marital[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $religion = $account->field_profile_religion[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
    $school['url'] = $account->field_profile_education[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['url'];
    $school['title'] = $account->field_profile_education[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['title'];
    $location['street'] = $account->locations[0]['street'];
    $location['city'] = $account->locations[0]['city'];
    $location['state'] = $account->locations[0]['province_name'];
```

Then to display the fields;

```
<div>
    <h2>Personal Info</h2>
          <?php if ($fname && $lname): ?> Name: <?php echo $fname." ".$lname ."<br>"; ?> <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if ($dob): ?> Date of Birth: <?php $dob = preg_replace('/00:00:00/',"",$dob); echo $dob . "<br>"; ?> <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if ($marital): ?> Marital Status: <?php echo $marital ."<br>"; ?> <?php endif; ?>
          <?php if ($religion): ?> Religion: <?php echo $religion ."<br>"; ?> <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    
    <h2>Contact Info</h2>
    <div>
        <?php if ($location['street']): ?> <?php echo $location['street'] ."<br>"; ?> <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($location['city']): ?><?php echo $location['city'] .", "; ?> <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($location['state']): ?><?php echo $location['state'] ."<br>"; ?> <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($phone): ?> Phone: <?php echo $phone ."<br>"; ?> <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    
    <h2>Education</h2>
    <div>
        <?php if ($school): ?>
        
            <?php echo "<a href='".$school['url']."' target='_blank'>".$school['title']."</a><br>"; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    
    <br>
    
    <h2>Bio</h2>
    <div>
        <?php if ($bio): ?><?php echo $bio ."<br>"; ?> <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

But am getting errors;

```
Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line 70 of /sites/all/modules/author_pane/author-pane.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line 71 of /sites/all/modules/author_pane/author-pane.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line 72 of /sites/all/modules/author_pane/author-pane.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line 73 of /sites/all/modules/author_pane/author-pane.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line 74 of /sites/all/modules/author_pane/author-pane.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined index: und in include() (line 75 of /sites/all/modules/author_pane/author-pane.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in include() (line 76 of /sites/all/modules/author_pane/author-pane.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in include() (line 77 of /sites/all/modules/author_pane/author-pane.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in include() (line 78 of /sites/all/modules/author_pane/author-pane.tpl.php).
```

Now I know that the und errors are related to the language according to this post. http://drupal.org/node/1422606

Although when I tried to structure my code within the author_pane.module, I was getting a 500 error on my server. So, to restate my question. What is the proper way to accomplish this?

EDIT/CLARIFICATION: When I say "proper way to accomplish this", I want to know if placing this code within .tpl file or .module and if am calling the field correctly.

Comment: Is your site in english/one language? What does the $account variable look like when you dpm() it?

Comment: It is english. The $account var contains all the info associated with the user being called by author pane.

Comment: Yes, but take a look at it with devels DPM and confirm that it is actually structured that way.  I have a feeling that you will find that it is using language codes instead of the default "und" i.e. "LANGUAGE_NONE".

Comment: This is what one of the fields looks like when I do a print_r. I can't use devel because it causes errors on my site. [field_profile_firstname] => Array ( [und] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => DigitalFire [format] => [safe_value] => DigitalFire ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a view of the fields you'd like in the author bio area. Be sure and use contextual filters to show only the author passed.

Use Viewfield module to show this view for the content type as a field. Set it to show the author id as a contextual filter to the view.

Done. :-)